# Is there a way to build trees in Biopython Phylotree from scratch?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, phylogeny

I am trying to build a binary tree using Biopython Phylo, but I can't add new children to a current node, and I don't have an XML file or any kind of similar data to read from. I just want to write the code so that it builds and draws a tree with varying edge sizes. Here is my code:

```
from Bio.Phylo.BaseTree import Tree, Clade
from Bio import Phylo

lengths = [10, 12, 32, 44]
tree = Tree(rooted='True')
s = Clade(branch_length=lengths[0], clades = [Clade(branch_length=lengths[1]), Clade(branch_length=lengths[2])])
Phylo.draw(s)
```

[a binary tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkNSR.png)

Adding any new clades into the list only adds new branches that are at the same generation as this, but I want to extend the tree by adding more children to the two existing branches.
I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

I found it! Here is a small example:

```
t = Tree(rooted='True')
c = Clade(branch_length=10, clades=[Clade(12, clades=[Clade(10), Clade(5)]), Clade(14)])
Phylo.draw(c)
```

There should be `clades()` inside a `Clade()`.
Probably no easy way to make it iterative.
[image]